# Gem error on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bundle install on rails does not complete due to the following error:
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/jbuilder-2.2.5.gem)
An error occurred while installing jbuilder (2.2.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install jbuilder -v '2.2.5'` succeeds before bundling.

Each time I try to bundle install or bundle update, I get the same error.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Interesting. What version of `bundler` gem do you have?

Comment: please expand your answer as an asnwer below, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got the solution to my problem. Looks like I was running an old version of bundler.
So I updated the version of bundler and then installed the required gem. Bundler version information and commands can be found on http://bundler.io/. It works perfectly fine now!